# If/Else statement not working in JQuery (using Javascript inside Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to run an if/else statement depending on the value of a variable inside Bootstrap 3.1. Why isn't this code working? I have tried many variations of it, with and without return... but it will not return the right class depending on the window width. I have refreshed and checked that the value for windowwidth is both above and below 750... no change. How can I go about this within Bootstrap.js?

```
var windowwidth = $(window).width();


if (!isActive) {
 if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && !$parent.closest('.navbar-nav').length) {
   // if mobile we use a backdrop because click events don't delegate
 $('<div class="dropdown-backdrop"/>').insertAfter($(this)).on('click', clearMenus)
}


var relatedTarget = { relatedTarget: this }
$parent.trigger(e = $.Event('show.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))

if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

$parent
//Code starts here//

 if (windowwidth < 750) {
  return .toggleClass('open')
 }
 else {
  return .toggleClass('otherclass')
 }
//code ends here//
  .trigger('shown.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget)

$this.focus()
}

return false
}
```

Comment: Please post the real code you have, this can't be true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code to this. Your attempt was wrong syntax.

```
 var class = windowwidth < 750 ? 'open' : 'otherclass';
 $parent
     .toggleClass(class)
     .trigger('shown.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$parent.toggleClass((windowwidth < 750)?'open':'otherclass'))` instead.

The problem is two-fold: returning from the if-else makes you exit the function and you cannot `return .toggleClass` because there is no instance for the `.` to use to find an attribute (it's missing an argument).

If you cannot use a ternary operator (the whole `(boolean)?run on true: run on false`), maybe consider:

```
if(windowwidth < 750)
    $parent.toggleClass('open');
else
    $parent.toggleClass('otherclass');
```